# How do you throw an instance of an Exception class created through reflection?

Tags: java, exception, reflection

I am trying to create a function that throws an exception based on the type that you pass in.

```
private void myFunc(Class<?> exceptionType) {
   ...do some work...
   throw new exceptionOfTypeExceptionTypePassedIn(newMessage);
}
```

Can you do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, the `throw` statement only works with reference expressions of `Throwable` or its subtypes. Therefore, the expression you pass to your `throw` must have that type. You can achieve this, by providing a bound for the `exceptionType` parameter.

```
private void myFunc(Class<? extends Throwable> exceptionType) {
```

If you now want to restrict the type of `Throwable` subtype, you can do that too.

If it's `Exception`, you'll need a `throws` declaration

```
private void myFunc(Class<? extends Exception> exceptionType) throws Exception {
```

If it's `RuntimeException`, it won't

```
private void myFunc(Class<? extends RuntimeException> exceptionType) {
```

Depending on what you need, you might actually make the method generic. It would then look like this

```
private <T extends Throwable> void myFunc(Class<T> exceptionType) throws T {
```

As for the actual reflection logic, you are making the assumption that the corresponding type has an accessible constructor which accepts a `String` argument. If it doesn't, Java will throw all sorts of exceptions of its own. You need to handle these.

A potential solution would look like this ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) for `Class#getConstructor`, [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) for `Constructor#newInstance`)

```
private <T extends Throwable> void myFunc(Class<T> exceptionType) throws T {
    final String message = "some message";
    try {
        throw exceptionType.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(message);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // rethrow
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // rethrow
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // rethrow
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // rethrow
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // rethrow
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // rethrow
    }
}
```

You can obviously collapse all those exception types into a multi-catch statement.

Note that if the exception type you passed in was one of those mentioned in the existing `catch` statements, it will be swallowed, ie. not thrown. You can also add all those in a `throws` declaration of its own.

```
private static <T extends Throwable> void myFunc(Class<T> exceptionType) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, T {
    final String message = "some message";
    throw exceptionType.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(message);
}
```

or rethrow the caught exceptions wrapped in a `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `newInstance` method on the `Class` object.

Comment: Given `new exceptionOfTypeExceptionTypePassedIn(newMessage);`, I think they are trying to pass an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Reflection is pretty messy. The accepted answer works, but your code will be harder to follow. You're probably better off refactoring your code to avoid this situation.